# How to fix the error "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'rules' method"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a following code for the form validation:

```
         $('form').validate({
             errorElement: "div",

             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 $('.error-messages').append(error);
             },

             submitHandler: function() {
                 console.log("Таблица успешно обновлена!")
             }
        });

        $('.validating').rules('add', {
            rules: {
                number: true
            },
            messages: {
                number: "Введите цифры"
            },
        });
```

I tried to set the same messages for all `.validating` elements, but I had a following error in the console: "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'rules' method". How to fix that? Thank you in advance. 
The full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/d2pge08f/1/

Comment: `I tried to put the text of the messages for price_from and price_to into a variable`- in which variable? don't understand your question, please explain more clean what do you need

Comment: I have already refactored my code, and I'll rephrase the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem in the following way:

```
$('form').validate({
             errorElement: "div",

             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 $('.error-messages').append(error);
             },

             submitHandler: function() {
                console.log("Таблица успешно обновлена!")
            }
        });

        $('.validating').each(function() {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                number: true,
                messages: {
                    number: "Введите цифры"
                },
            });
        });
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/waLgfv6m/

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/ the add function in

```
$('.validating').rules('add', {
    number: true,
    messages: {
        number: "Введите цифры"
    },
});
```

will add rules for AN element, in your case only to the first maybe. Hence they use id in the documentation...

the first version of your code should do it:

```js
$('form').validate({
     rules: {
        price_from: {
            number: true
        },
        price_to: {
            number: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        price_from: {
            number: "Введите цифры"
        },
        price_to: {
            number: "Введите цифры"
        }
    },

    errorElement: "div",

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $('.error-messages').append(error);
    },

    submitHandler: function() {
        this.successList.map(function(field){
              console.log($(field).attr("name"), $(field).val())
          })
        console.log("Таблица успешно обновлена!")
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.price-filter {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
    form {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .price-filter input {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        outline: none;
    }
    
.error-messages {
     color: red;
     margin-top: 5px;
}

input.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="price-filter wrapper">
            <form action="/" name="form">
                <label>Цена от:</label>
                <input class="price-from validating" name="price_from" type="text" placeholder="0">
                <label>до:</label>
                <input class="price-to validating" name="price_to" type="text" placeholder="10000">
                <input class="refresh" type="submit" value="Обновить">
                <div class="error-messages"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but error still exists. I tried to put element selector instead of field, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Sry I guess I posed the answer before you refactor your code. The answer does work for the first version of the code. https://jsfiddle.net/_kdts/qr0sogmw/15/

Comment: Nothing to worry, I'm still working to solve the issue

Comment: I see you edited your answer. I decided to return to old version of code, and just edited the 'name" attribute of `input` elements. It allowed me to set one message for the both of `input` elements. Thanks for answer!

Comment: For jQuery Validate methods such as `.validate()` and `.rules()`, when selecting more than one element at a time, these methods must be wrapped within a jQuery `.each()` in order to attach them to all matched elements in the group.